# Issues with nested structures and dynamic memory allocation

Tags: arrays, c, structure

I'm using nested structures and dynamic memory allocation and I'm having problems.

I'm using the following input:

Member ID: 1
Member Name: A
Policy Number: 1

Policy ID: P1
Policy Type: 1
Policy Premium: 100

However, I'm not able to enter anything else after I enter P1. The program terminates.

The other issue I'm having, is that when I select option 2, which is supposed to print all members, it doesn't display correctly.

Even before entering any member details, if I choose option 2, it displays the following:

Member ID: 0
Member Name:

I'm wondering if when creating the dynamic array, I've made a mistake, and it's actually printing member[0].
After adding members to the array, then choosing option 2, it prints:

Member ID: 1
Member Name: A
Policy ID: (null)
Policy Type: Premium: $100

It prints the member details, but when it comes to accessing the policy for that member, those details don't print, and it completely skips over the
policy type.

Full code below:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum enumtype { Car, Health, Travel, Pet };

typedef struct policy {
        char id[4];
        enum enumtype type;
        int premium;
}pol;

typedef struct member {
    int id;
    char name[30];
    int polnum;
    pol *policy;
}mem;

mem getmember() {
    mem member;
    int i, j;

    printf("\n\nEnter member's details");
    printf("\nMember ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &member.id);
    printf("Member Name: ");
    scanf(" %s", member.name);
    printf("Requested number of policies: ");
    scanf("%d", &member.polnum);

    if (member.polnum > 0) { 
        printf("\nEnter policy details for %s", member.name);
        for (i = 0; i < member.polnum; i++) {
            printf("\nEnter details for policy %d", i + 1);
            printf("\nEnter Policy ID: ");
            scanf(" %s", member.policy->id);

            printf("\nEnter Policy Type:");
            printf("\n1 - Car");
            printf("\n2 - Health");
            printf("\n3 - Travel");
            printf("\n4 - Pet");
            printf("\n\nEnter an option: ");
            scanf("%d", &member.policy[i].type);

            while (member.policy[i].type < 1 || member.policy[i].type > 4) {
                printf("\nInvalid policy type");
                printf("\nPlease enter a number from 1 - 4: ");
                scanf("%d", &member.policy[i].type);
            }

            printf("\nEnter Premium: $");
            scanf("%d", &member.policy[i].premium);

            while (member.policy[i].premium < 0) {
                printf("Invalid premium");
                printf("\nPremium must be a positive value");
                printf("\nEnter Premium: $");
                scanf("%d", &member.policy[i].premium);
            }
        }
    }
    else
        member.policy = NULL;
    
    return member;
}

void printmember(mem* member, int memNum) {

    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i = memNum+1; i++) { // This still doesn't print properly but I don't know why
        //printf("\nDetails for Member %d", i + 1);
        printf("\n\nMember ID: %d", member[i].id);
        printf("\nMember Name: %s", member[i].name);

        for (j = 0; j < member[i].polnum; j++) {
            printf("\nPolicy ID: %s", member[i].policy[j].id);
            printf("\nPolicy Type: ", member[i].policy[j].type);
            switch (member[i].policy[j].type) { 
            case 1:
                printf("Car");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Health");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Travel");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Pet");
                break;
            }
            
            printf("Premium: $%d", member[i].policy[j].premium);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    int memNum = 0;
    char name[30];
    mem* member = NULL;
    member = (mem*)realloc(member, (memNum++) * sizeof(member));


    while (choice != 3) {
        
        choice = 0;
        printf("\n\t   Menu");
        printf("\n-----------------------------");
        printf("\n1 - Add new member");
        printf("\n2 - Display all members");
        printf("\n3 - Exit");
        
        printf("\n\nEnter an option: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            member = (mem*)realloc(member, (memNum + 1) * sizeof(member));
            member[memNum++] = getmember();
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\n\nDisplaying all members");
            printmember(member, memNum);
            break;
        case 3:
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(member)` -> `sizeof(*member)`

Comment: You *must* *always* check the value returned by scanf.  If there is a non-digit value in the input stream, then `scanf("%d", &choice);` will return 0 and not modify the value of `choice`.  If its value was previously 3, the code will exit.  That is probably why you see sporadic exits when you think you're entering '1'.  Always check the return value.

Comment: `scanf(" %s", &member.name);` without a width limit is _bad_.  Use `scanf("%3s", &member.name);`.

Comment: "I'm not sure why it does this." --> Without posted input and knowing your output, makes the question more difficult.  Post your input used, output seen, output expected.

Comment: @kaylum What does that change? I've tried it, but can't see a difference in output.

Comment: @WetWizard Best to update your question with this info.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica

Sorry about that! 
I've added the requested info to the question.

Comment: @WilliamPursell

Adding a choice=0; line before asking the user to input an option fixed that problem. Thanks!

Comment: @WetWizard `sizeof(member)` is a size of one pointer. `sizeof(*member)` is the size of the structure that the pointer points to and is the size you need.

Comment: `structurepointer->member` is shorthand for `(*structurepointer).member`. When you have multiple structure pointers, it's a very good thing. It is used often. In fact, Java, which relies on dynamic allocation more often, did away with dot and made arrow dot (I think; not an expert on Java, but it seems they did.)

Comment: Why did you delete all your code?

Comment: The question has been damaged — close to beyond repair.  It isn't clear which revision it should be rolled back to.  Given the damage, I'm going to vote to close.  As it stands (no code on display), it needs more details.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There were still significant issues, and I wasn't able to get a comprehensive answer for the "why" things didn't work, or what I was doing wrong. I truly appreciate the help, but none of it gave me viable code. In the end I paid a tutor to help me understand and correct it. Thanks again for the effort, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct member {
    int id;
    char name[30];
    int polnum;

    struct policy {
        char id[4];
        enum enumtype type;
        int premium;
    }pol;
}mem;
```

You can have `n` members and each member can have `polnum` policies, but that's not what this struct says. This struct says each member has one policy that is represented by a nested structure. Your outer `realloc` keeping members in an array constrains the solution space. We can't actually do that and use a stretchy structure at the same time, so I don't have to get into how. We just do this the way you already know how.

```
typedef struct struct policy {
        char id[4];
        enum enumtype type;
        int premium;
} pol;

typedef struct member {
    int id;
    char name[30];
    int polnum;
    pol *policies;
}mem;
```

Adding policies is like so:

```
    if (member.polnum > 0) { 
        member.pol = malloc(member.polnum * sizeof(pol));
        printf("\nEnter policy details for %s", member.name);
        for (i = 0; i < member.polnum; i++) {
             //...
             scanf("%d", &member.pol[i].type);
             //...
         }
     } else {
         member.pol = NULL; // When you go to write the free memory code you will thank me
     }
```

In print member, we have a very similar construct:

```
        for (j = 0; j < member[i].polnum; j++) {
            printf("\nPolicy ID: %s", member[i].pol[j].type);
```

Administrative note: code was removed from question after answer posted.

Comment: So I made the changes you suggested, but I'm still having a few problems and I'm hoping you can help. I've updated the post with the new code and the continuing problems.

Comment: @WetWizard: From your code: `scanf(" %s", member.policy->id);`: not completely updated. Anyway, you now have the idea and it's just a debugging problem.

Comment: Or the code could use a flexible array member for the policies.  The structure defined within another structure is legitimate, though unusual.  The nested definition does not stop the `struct policy` type being used in other contexts too (this is not C++).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: In order to use a flexible array member, the outer array from realloc would have to be pointers to structures rather than structures (bigger change), so I didn't go that way.

Comment: Fair comment. .